# jquery .prop() doesn't work for checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

Banging my head on a very simple problem (if you know where to look for it I suppose) I ask for your advice.

I have a table like this built from PHP:

```
echo '<tr><td class="report"><input type="checkbox" id="crediti['.$i.']" name="crediti['.$i.']" value="'.$cred['id_cre'].'" ';
    if($check == 1){ echo "checked";}else{ echo "";}
    echo' /></td><td class="report">'.$cred['id_cre'].'</td>
    <td class="report">'.number_format($cred['gbv_tot'],'2',',','.').'</td>
    <td class="report"><input class="input_field" type="text" name="chiesto['.$i.']" value="'.$chiesto.'"></td>
    <td class="report"><input type="text" name="ammesso['.$i.']" value="'.$ammesso.'"></td>
    <td class="report"><input type="text" name="data_ammesso['.$i.']" value="'.$data_ammesso.'" class="data_field"></td></tr>';
```

I have also some jquery code to check each checkbox if the user enters a value in one of the input fields of the row.

```
$('.input_field').blur(function(){
    if($(this).val()!=''){
        $(this).closest("input").prop("checked", true); 
    }
});
```

I have verified that the selector is identifying the right checkbox but I cannot manage to turn that checkbox to selected. Nothing is thrown as an error. Just nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Where should I look for the error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target the checkbox in the same row.

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) find an matching ancestor element, so the checkbox is not a ancestor of the checkbox element that is why it is not working.

You need to find the `tr` parent of the changed field then find the checkbox within it.

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: Close to the solution. This code check all the checkboxes (one for each row). Dunno why but console.log( $(this).closest("input").attr("name");) was returning the name of the desired checkbox...

Comment: @LelioFaieta then change the selector `input:checkbox` to `input[name="yourcheckboxname"]` or `input:checkbox` to `input[name="yourcheckboxname"]:checkbox`

Comment: thanks! I was executing $('.input_field').closest("tr"). instead of $(this).closest("tr"). so now your code is working fine! Thanks again!